# Prove that CAB is acute

Tags: geometry

In triangle ABC the medians of B and C intersect at point M and angle BMC = 70°. Prove that angle CAB is acute.

You can only use elementary geometry (no trigonometry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B_1$ and $C_1$ be midpoints of $AC, AB$ respectively. Then, $$\begin{array}{rl}70^\circ&=\angle BMC\\&=\angle MB_1C+\angle MCB_1\\&>\angle MB_1C\\&=\angle BAB_1+\angle ABB_1\\&>\angle BAB_1\\&=\angle CAB\end{array}$$

(repeatedly used the fact that an exterior angle of the triangle is equal to the sum of the two non-adjacent interior angles), so $\angle CAB$ is not only acute - it is less than $70^\circ$.

We never used that $B_1$ and $C_1$ were midpoints, by the way.